$U_2$ homeomorphic to $S^3 \times S^1$, how?
Recently, I have been reading Linear Groups, chapter 9, from Michael Artin, Algebra book.
There is a question in the exercise (Chapter 9, Exercise section 3, no.3.2), given as follows
Prove that $U_2$ is homeomorphic to the product $S^3 \times S^1$. Here $U_2$ is a set of all 2 by 2  unitary matrices.
Here is my approach to solve, but I am unable to get it:
I want to use polar decomposition here, so, $U_2= AP$ where $A$ is a unitary matrix and $P$ is a positive definite matrix. Still, after that, I can't control the decomposition to give a map from $U_2$ to $S^3 \times S^1$.

Polar decomposition is irrelevant here (the polar decomposition of a unitary matrix $U$ is $A = U, P = I$). You want to use the fact that $SU(2)$ is diffeomorphic to $S^3$.
